# Is there a solution for remote development for IntelliJ Community Edition?

Tags: ssh, remote, intellij-idea

I am using a [Coder](https://coder.com/) cloud instance to host my source code, and would like to develop out of IntelliJ locally on my workstation. The problem is I'm using IntelliJ Community Edition and [remote development is only available in IntelliJ Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/remote-development-starting-page.html).

Is there a way to do remote development using IntelliJ Community Edition? Perhaps through an IJ plugin or some other creative means?